# WordPress Theme Files Not Linking

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the last couple of days I have been creating a theme for my WordPress site, but suddenly I have experienced problems with it. The php files have stopped linking with the css files.
I have tried creating many different themes and have been getting the same result - a site that only looks like basic html.

Here is the coding I have been using to link them `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />`
Does anyone have any ideas? Is anybody else having problems with their site?

P.s. Any help will be very much appreciated!! :D

Comment: your included code isn't displaying :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try `/styles.css`, or `./styles.css`. The "." means "up one directory level".

However, a better way to do it, would be to link to it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

This creates a dynamic absolute path to the stylesheet.

As @rambu said below, [wp_enqueue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) is the *proper* way to do this.

```
function add_my_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_style' );
```

Comment: should use [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook for that